# podspec source :http unpacks to where?

Tags: http, cocoapods, podspec

A podspec I'm creating is downloading a zip archive through a :http source:

```
s.source = {
  :http => 'https://developer.spotify.com/download/libspotify/libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal.zip'
  }
```

I'm referring to files within the zip archive like so:

```
s.source_files = [
    'libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal/libspotify.framework/Versions/12.1.45/Headers/*.h'
    ]
s.preserve_paths = 'libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal/libspotify.framework/*'
s.xcconfig = {
  'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '\"$(PODS_ROOT)/libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal\"'
  }
```

Passes pod spec lint validation, and pod install works well too in a project where I try out my podspec. But when building I get the error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F"/Users/niklas/code/playground/libspotify podspec
>   test/Pods/libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal"' ld: framework not
>   found libspotify

Getting this error because FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS is incorrectly set. There's no folder for the downloaded zip archive in the PODS_ROOT directory.

Where should I point FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS to? Where's the extracted zip archive?

Comment: could this be related to using a local podspec? In the projects' Podfile I do pod 'name-here', :path => 'local-path-here'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug related to specifying a local podspec with `:path` in the Podfile. When I create my own repo and install through the repo the zip archive is unzipped in the `Pods` directory as expected.